# How to refer to the match order in the replace string?

Tags: regex, windows, perl

I'm looking for a way to type the *order of match* of the being-replaced-string among all other found-strings. For Example, for the 1st matched string, the value should be 1, for the 2nd it's 2 … for the nth it should be n. The value I'm looking for is the order of the matched string among all other matched strings.

**Example for what I'm trying to get**

Let's say that I have this original content ...

```
<"BOY"(GUN)><"GIRL"(BAG)><"SISTERS"(CANDY)><"JOHN"(HAT)>
```

... and I want it to be manipulated to be like this ...

```
1
BOY
GUN

2
GIRL
BAG

3
SISTERS
CANDY

4
JOHN
HAT
```

I already know that I need `<"(.*?)"\((.*?)\)>` to match each element. For the replace code I think I need something like `#MATCH ORDER REFERENCE#\n\$1\n$2\n`.

**Note**

- I'm using Perl on Windows.

Comment: Extract the matches into a list, then write a loop that formats the output the way you want it, including the index.  I don't believe there's an index reference in RE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `/e` modifier to evaluate the replacement. See [Regexp Quote-Like Operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators).

Then you can increase a counter on each replacement.

**Code**

```
my $text = '<"BOY"(GUN)><"GIRL"(BAG)><"SISTERS"(CANDY)><"JOHN"(HAT)>';
my $counter = 1;
$text =~ s/<"([^"]+)"\(([^()]+)\)>/$counter++."\n$1\n$2\n\n"/ge;

print $text;
```

**Output**

```
1
BOY
GUN

2
GIRL
BAG

3
SISTERS
CANDY

4
JOHN
HAT
```